# Which data structure to use for two elements in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

Which data structer should I use when I need to hold two unknown types as one object?

I need that two create a dictionary with value that can take two types.

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I think we need a little more here - example, goal?

Comment: You can put them into an `object[]` with two elements, or into a [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: If you're using .NET 4 or later, check out the [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: A `Tuple<T1,T2>` might be what you need. It's a generic type, and it can contain two different values in one object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
Tuple<TOne, TTwo> IndexCombiner<TOne, TTwo>(
    Table table,
    Func<Table, TOne> selectorOne,
    Func<Table, TTwo> selectorTwo)
{
    return Tuple.Create(selectorOne(table), selectorTwo(table));
}
```

as an example.